# App Store Security Q: mysterious peak in downloads from china for 30 days but not users

Tags: security, app-store

**Security Q: Weird peak in downloads of very old app from China over 30 days then 0 downloads.**

We noticed in Sep a sudden peak in App Download for an old iOS6 app were trying to kill off.

Went from 1, 2 downloads daily to 60/70 a day every day in Sep from China. Then suddenly dropped again.

Yet the number of daily users has not peaked.

It's an old iOS6 app were trying to kill off. And its a very niche product.
Not been updated since nov 2016.

Its used to log into our company systems.

**Should we be suspicious? security issue? 
Could there be an old security bug in an old build even if its run on newer iOS?**

Its not iOS 11 new iphone reinstalling from a backup I think. iOS 11 released on sep 17th. iphone 8 released 22 sep.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to reports in [Apple's own developer forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/community/distribution/app-store), a number of developers saw Sales and Trend reports showing huge numbers of downloads of their free iOS apps from China in the August-September timeframe, but without analytics saying that these apps were actually opened.

So it's probably nothing specific to your app, but instead some process that is affecting a large number of free iOS apps.  Some developers just disabled China in the iTC Territories Availability list for their free apps to get a better estimate of the download numbers from "real" users.

Comment: weird - for other users heres the full url to thread https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/267721#267721